# Discrete mathematics proof union/intersect/difference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove that $$A\cup B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)\cup (A\cap B)$$

I'm new to proofs so I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: See also: [Proving that $A\cup B=(A-B)\cup(B-A)\cup (A\cap B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632343). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24A%5Ccup%20B%3D(A%5Csetminus%20B)%5Ccup%20(B%5Csetminus%20A)%5Ccup%20(A%5Ccap%20B)%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3):

To show that two sets are equal, we must show that they are each subsets of the other. That is, you must show:

1. $A \cup B \subseteq (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B)$,
2. $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B) \subseteq A \cup B$.

To show that $X \subseteq Y$ we take any element $x \in X$ and we need to show that $x \in Y$.

Suppose $x \in A \cup B$, which means that $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. Now break it into cases:

- $x \in A$

  - $x \in B$ (then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ means $x \in A \cap B$)
  - $x \notin B$ (then $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$ means $x \in A \setminus B$)
- $x \in B$

  - $x \in A$ (then...)
  - $x \notin A$ (then...)

Now to show the second inclusion, suppose $x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B)$. Cases:

- $x \in A \setminus B$ (then...)
- $x \in B \setminus A$ (then...)
- $x \in A \cap B$ (then...)

You don't need to consider subcases here to show that $x \in A \cup B$.

Comment: *A side note for OP:* If you use *Venn diagram*, then the above answer will be much more clear (and easier to fill the blanks) to you. Nice answer @Trevor Gunn

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
&A=A\cap\left(B\cup B^C\right)=\left(A\cap B\right)\cup\left(A\cap B^C\right)=\left(A\cap B\right)\cup\left(A\setminus B\right)\\
&B=\left(B\cap A\right)\cup\left(B\setminus A\right)\\
&A\cup B=(A\cap B)\cup (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)
\end{align}

Comment: the problem is not subtraction. its \ which is the difference

Comment: @noslov I meant the difference, but changed the notation

Answer (score 2):

Venn diagrams are really useful when working with sets with the first time to get a grasp of the core concepts.

[image]